# Execute snakemake for iterative mapping

Tags: loops, iteration, mapping, bioinformatics, snakemake

I would like to use Snakemake for iterative mapping of my samples. I don't know beforehand how many times the samples have to be remapped. For certain samples it will probably be 2-3 times, for others 10 times. If I understand correctly, Snakemake cannot use while loops, but maybe some kind of checkpoint is possible?

Basically what I want to do in this loop is calling the fasta sequence for my Illumina reads each time until it doesn't change anymore. (this is done using bowtie2 >  samtools view > samtools mpileup > bcftools call > bcftools view > bcftools index > bcftools consensus)

I wrote previously a bash script to do this, but a Snakemake could really speed up this process. In the bash script, I used a R-script I wrote that counts the number of differences between the new and old fasta file. If this number is = 0, then it can stop the loop, if it is not the same then it has to rerun the steps above. Ideally, it should have a minimum of 3 loops and a max of 15 loops.

If someone could help, that would be fantastic!
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure snakemake is suitable to do the iteration logic, but if it is, it might probably require that the number of differences found at a given iteration be encoded in the file names. The final round would produce files with "0" in their names. One issue is that a rule should be able to know in advance how its input should be named based on how its output is named, but generation "0" will not necessarily be the child of generation "1".

Comment: If the number of iterations is determined in advance (say 15), then you can decide that "generation numbers" in file names will be from 14 to 0, regardless of the actual number of differences, but you will have useless steps if actual zero is reached before generation "0".

Comment: Indeed, I do put a maximum (otherwise in some cases this would never end). For the moment I constructed it by using a for loop (for in in {0..15}) with a break into if the loop has minimally run 5 times and if there are no changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since your sequence of steps `bowtie2 > samtools view > samtools mpileup ...` has to be done serially, *i.e.* it cannot be parallelized for a given input fastq, I think I would do what you describe in your bash script. Something like, largely pseudocode:

```
rule all:
    input:
        ['a.consensus.fastq', 'b.consensus.fastq', ...]

rule iterative_mapping:
    input:
        fq= '{sample}.fastq',
    output:
        fq= '{sample}.consensus.fastq',
    run:
        i = 0
        while i < 15 and fastq has changed:
            shell("bowtie2 > samtools view ...")
            shell("check_fastq_has_changed.R ...")
```

This will do the iterative mapping in parallel for the different `{sample}`s. Does it make sense?

Comment: Indeed, for now I solved it like this, but I was hoping there was another way. Unfortunately I have the impression this will be difficult.

Comment: @LauraVP I'd be curious to know of other strategies either from existing workflow managers or entirely hypothetical. To me the solution above looks pretty good and since you use python code for the logic you have a lot of control and readability (better than the equivalent in bash).

Comment: @dariober I suppose an "ideal" solution would have a separate rule for each shell step, in order to benefit from snakemake job management.